# Not able to print

Tags: 18.04, printing

I have sucessfully installed the drivers of my printer Samsung Xpress M2026W.

Now what should I do? 
I am not able to print yet.

Comment: What ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: @Gryu 18.04.4 LTS I followed this method: cd Download && tar -xzvf uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz --------- cd uld && sud ./install.sh

Comment: What does your **Settings -> Printers** or **Settings -> Devices -> Printers** show?

Comment: Look at this: https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/VPSPrinterUbuntu

Comment: There is a generic printer I think : CUPS-BRF-Printer ...

Comment: Ok. Is there your printer listed?

Comment: Point a browser at `http://localhost:631`, the CUPS management interface. Under the "Administration" tab, you can add a printer.

Comment: @Gryu The printer is not listed, I'm afraid